# pushing into heroku repo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I am currently learning how to use Heroku and I'm having a bit of trouble.

When I type the commands

```
    git push heroku master
```

I get the message

```
    Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '50.19.85.156' to the list of known hosts.
    Permission denied (publickey).
```

I currently have git set up on my computer with RSA key added for my machine.

I'm assuming there is a separate RSA key that I need to add to my heroku account? I'm not entirely sure.

****EDIT**************************

I found out what was wrong. I needed to add my key

```
    heroku keys:add ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

However, I am having another problem now.

Basically, I created an rails app I wanted to upload but I deleted it on my heroku account. I created another app and I want to use this app. However when I

```
    git push heroku master
```

I will get the message

```
    No such app as rocky-gorge-9306
```

Where rocky-gorge-9306 is my previous app, not the new one that I create

When I enter the command

```
    git remote -v
```

I get

```
    heroku  git@heroku.com:rocky-gorge-9306.git (fetch)  <---- old deleted app that does not exist 
    heroku  git@heroku.com:rocky-gorge-9306.git (push)
    origin  https://github.com/liondancer/first_app.git (fetch)
    origin  https://github.com/liondancer/first_app.git (push)
```

Comment: most probably you need to login to heroku https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-command#logging-in

Comment: I already logged in before pushing

Comment: are you sure that the remote heroku points to your application git repo on heroku? Make sure that git url in `heroku apps:info --app your-app-name` and `git remote -v show heroku` are same.

Comment: I think I'm getting confused ;/ I'm trying to upload my RoR app onto heroku

Comment: Yes, I understand that. To upload your app an heroku you push your code to heroku like you do on github. For that you should be able to establish a ssh connection to heroku and you should have rights to push to the remote repo. First comment was to make sure that you can ssh to heroku, second was to make sure that you are pushing to the correct repo, the repo you have rights to push to.

Comment: Hmm @rubish the only thing that doesn't occur when I login is         Uploading ssh public key /Users/joe/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

Instead it just says "Authentication successful"

Comment: @rubish also, When I put in the command "git remote -v heroku", I get the same error messages

Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32881/discussion-between-liondancer-and-rubish)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, you have public/private keys on your development machine. If not, 
do the following:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

**Heroku configuration**

1. Install [Heroku Toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/)
2. Configure your Heroku account: `heroku login`
3. Verify, your git heroku configured properly: `git remote -v`.
   If not, do the following: `heroku git:remote -a your_heroku_app_name`
4. Now you should be able to push to heroku: `git push heroku master`

Comment: Try to create a new rails app and heroku: 1. rails new mytest 2. cd mytest 3. git init 4. git add .; git commit -am 'initial import' 5. heroku create 6. git push heroku master